# My texture pack won't show up in client

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I used [the most recent article](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Creating_a_resource_pack#Formatting_pack.mcmeta) I could find to help with this and I'm still having trouble. I've triple checked my formatting, doing exactly as the article tells me to, but I can't get the pack to show up in my client. I haven't added any content yet since I want to make sure the pack works. I saw some other posts like this one but I've made sure to check I didn't make the same mistakes. [resourcepacks folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNAKy.png)
[image: my resource pack folder][image][image] I believe it's everywhere it needs to be in my files and it still doesn't show up in the client. (For those wondering the top 2 aren't mine) This is my first time making a resource pack so sorry if I seem dumb.

edit: it might be that my resource pack isn't zipped? But I can't figure out how to zip a file I've created

Comment: Your minecraft version? You have to zip it as well.

Comment: @Phoenix You don't have to zip it.

Comment: I don't know if this makes a difference but what encoding are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means but everything I've done is in the linked article

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have show file extensions enabled, from what I can see, the file type description says Text File for the `pack.mcmeta` file this is because the actual filename is `pack.mcmeta.txt`, not `pack.mcmeta` as file explorer says. In order to actually change the file extension, you'll have to enable show file extensions in the "View" tab in File Explorer. Then remove the `.txt` file extension.

Ignore any warning about changing file extensions as this is irrelevant due to the fact that these are both plaintext files.

[image: show file extensions]

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is specifically that Minecraft requires a `.zip`, and you are using Windows, Windows has a built-in option to zip your resource pack. Just select the folders/files for the resource pack, and then click `Send to` > `Compressed file`. There are also various 3rd-party applications such as Winrar, and 7zip that can do this for you as well.

Comment: @Pheonix I can't figure out how to do this, when I zip the files nothing happens, the folders remain the same and the name of the folder does not change to .zip. I might be doing something wrong when I try to compress it though. Since I can't post images I'll try to describe . I right-click my resource pack in resourcepacks from the .minecraft folder. I click 7zip, I press "Compress and email..." and it takes me to a screen with various options. I hit OK without changing anything and the file comes out with no changes. Is there something I'm doing wrong there?

Comment: You're... trying to email according to the option. Open the 7zip GUI, select the relevant files and folders, then press add.

Comment: Apologies, I have fixed the problem. I hadn't formatted the pack.mcmeta file correctly. All is well